# Facebook Graph API: Read Comments from Facebook Post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to read the comments from the following post using Facebook Graph API with a valid access token. But unfortunately I fail:

https://graph.facebook.com/100000574361909_271940626184090/comments?access_token=XXX

For this post it works fine:

https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552_10150189643478553/comments?access_token=XXX

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What's the response you get back from the Facebook server?

Answer (score 2):

You can try following :
https://graph.facebook.com/190536810972971_373484936008056/comments?access_token=<>